# After finding a matching value, return a different value in corresponding row

Tags: excel, vba

Every day for work, I have around 400 unique values and I need to search for that value in a different sheet and pull a corresponding value back to the original sheet. I figured I'd take a shot at automating this as it's incredibly tedious to CRTL-F, CRTL-C, CRTL-V 400 times a day.

To (attempt) to explain this better, I've set up a scenario below:

**Worksheet("BattleOfEndor")**

Name

Han Solo

RedLeader1

RedSquadron1

RedSquadron2

RedSquadron4

BlueLeader1

BlueSquadron4

**Worksheet("Rebel Alliance Personnel: Ship and Weapon Preferences")**

(assume spaces are column breaks)

Name Ship Weapon

Luke_Skywalker X-Wing Lightsaber

Leia_Skywalker N/A Blaster

Gial_Ackbar Home_One N/A

Han_Solo YT-1300_492727ZED Blaster

RedLeader1 X-Wing Blaster

RedSquadron1 X-Wing Blaster

RedSquadron2 X-Wing Blaster

RedSquadron3 X-Wing Blaster

RedSquadron4 Y-Wing Blaster

RedSquadron5 Y-Wing Blaster

BlueLeader1 Z-95 Blaster

BlueSquadron1 X-Wing Blaster

BlueSquadron2 X-Wing Blaster

BlueSquadron3 Y-Wing Blaster

BlueSquadron4 Y-Wing Blaster

BlueSquadron5 Y-Wing Blaster

So regardless of who is first in the battle, I want my code to find him/her in my alternate sheet, copy his ship value and paste it in the adjacent column in the battle spreadsheet, then move to the next person in the battle to find out what ship they'd prefer to fly.

```
Dim Count As Integer
Dim Target As String

While Count < 433
Count = Count + 1
Target = Worksheets("BattleOfEndor").Range("A2:A433").Cells(Count)

With Worksheets("Rebel Alliance Personnel: Ship and Weapon Preferences").Range("H2:H433")
Dim C As Range
Set C = .Find(Target, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

I've copied much of the above from some other answers that related back to the .find or .findnext but I'm stumped on what my next steps are.

Any ideas? Am I even close?

Comment: And using vlookup will not work?

Comment: In B2 `=Vlookup(A2,'Rebel Alliance Personnel: Ship and Weapon Preferences'!A:C,2,False)` and Fill Down.

Comment: Scott- Vlookup was my first goto but it returns "Data Type Mismatch" even though both cell values are set to "Text". I have a special character in the cell, " ' ", which I think is throwing it off.

Comment: I can't figure out how to format my comment reply to format the code either......

Comment: So you have a column filled with numbers or something else that you have forced to be text by placing the single quote in front?

Comment: This may be one of those instances where we need a copy of your true data to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have a worksheet with ":" in the name,

Try this Looping code, change the names of the worksheets accordingly.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim LsRw As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range, x As Range
    Dim Lr As Long, Wrng As Range

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Names")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Weapons")

    With sh1
        LsRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("A2:A" & LsRw)
    End With

    With sh2
        Lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Wrng = .Range("H2:H" & Lr)
    End With

    For Each c In Rng.Cells
        For Each x In Wrng
            If x = c Then
                c.Offset(0, 1) = x.Offset(0, 1)
                c.Offset(0, 2) = x.Offset(0, 2)
            End If
        Next x
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dave- I tried copying and pasting the code in and changing the worksheet names to match my read document but I had no luck. I appreciate the effort you put in though!

Comment: I edited the code for column H like you had in your original code, show a picture of the sheet and columns if it doesn't work